# Variable declaration in a header file

Tags: c, header

In case I have a variable that may be used in several sources - is it a good practice to declare it in a header? or is it better to declare it in a `.c` file and use `extern` in other files?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

You should *declare* the variable in a header file:

```
extern int x;
```

and then *define* it in *one* C file:

```
int x;
```

In C, the difference between a definition and a declaration is that the definition reserves space for the variable, whereas the declaration merely introduces the variable into the symbol table (and will cause the linker to go looking for it when it comes to link time).

Comment: **Both** are declarations! At file-scope, the second is not a (full) definition, but a _tentative definition_.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite What is supposed to be the difference between the two types of definitions? And what do you mean by file-scope?

Answer (score 51):

You should declare it as `extern` in a header file, and define it in exactly 1 .c file.

Note that the .c file should also use the header and so the standard pattern looks like:

```
// file.h
extern int x;  // declaration

// file.c
#include "file.h"
int x = 1;    // definition and re-declaration
```

re-definition is an error but re-declaration is Ok and often necessary.

Comment: Indeed it *should* always use the header, so that if the types get out of whack between the declaration and definition the compiler will tell you.

Comment: cat, you're right, I'll re-word it a little.

Answer (score 21):

If you declare it like

```
int x;
```

in a header file which is then included in multiple places, you'll end up with multiple instances of x (and potentially compile or link problems).

The correct way to approach this is to have the header file say

```
extern int x; /* declared in foo.c */
```

and then in foo.c you can say

```
int x; /* exported in foo.h */
```

THen you can include your header file in as many places as you like.

Answer (score 4):

The key is to keep the declarations of the variable in the header file and source file the same.

I use this trick

```
------sample.c------
#define sample_c
#include sample.h

(rest of sample .c)

------sample.h------
#ifdef sample_c
#define EXTERN
#else
#define EXTERN extern
#endif

EXTERN int x;
```

Sample.c is only compiled once and it defines the variables.  Any file that includes sample.h is only given the "extern" of the variable; it does allocate space for that variable.

When you change the type of x, it will change for everybody.  You won't need to remember to change it in the source file and the header file.

Comment: How do you deal with initialisation? - extern int x = 6; would give a warning on most compilers.

Comment: @chrisharris - that is a limitation.  I usually have an Init() in each module to initialize variables.

Comment: Don't you find it less cumbersome to have extern declaration in the header and definition in the C file? As @caf commented, if the types don't match you get a warning (I do always include the header file in the corresponding c file anyway, since I require all functions to have a prototype).

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution?

```
#ifndef VERSION_H
#define VERSION_H

static const char SVER[] = "14.2.1";
static const char AVER[] = "1.1.0.0";

#else

extern static const char SVER[];
extern static const char AVER[];

#endif /*VERSION_H */
```

The only draw back I see is that the include guard doesn't save you if you include it twice in the same file.

Comment: 1) The #ifndef guard prevents multiple definitions in a *single* source file (thus the extern definitions do nothing). 2) Declaring a static variable in a header means that each source file that includes it will have its own version of that variable rather than a single shared variable. Technically this will link, but behavior may not be desired (may not notice as you used const variables in this example, but use it for something non-const and you'll see it matters). Accepted answer is almost always the appropriate solution.