# Error with linker for a extern variable declared in a header file

Tags: c, linker-errors

I have a header file a.h which is included in 2 .c files a.c and b.c

a.h

```
#ifndef A_H_INCLUDE
#define A_H_INCLUDE
extern int g;
void chk(int f);
#endif
```

a.c

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include "a.h"

void chk(int f)
{
    if(g==1) printf("\n CORRECT\n");
    else printf("\n INcorrect::%d: \n",f);
}
```

b.c

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include "a.h"

int main()
{
  int g;
  printf("\n ENTER::");
  scanf("%d",&g);
  chk(56);
  return 0;
}
```

On compiling the code it is giving me error

```
gcc a.c b.c a.h -o j
/tmp/ccEerIPj.o: In function `chk':
a.c:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `g'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have already checked [Variable declaration in a header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164167/variable-declaration-in-a-header-file) and i guess i am doing the same thing.

Any suggestion or pointer to problem in code will be appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `int g;` to the global scope of your `a.c` file to provide a definition for the variable.

(In case you're wondering, the *local* variable inside your `main()` function has *no* linkage, since it's an automatic variable at block scope. It has nothing to do with your problem.)