# What's wrong with my include guards?

Tags: c

C noob here. I have a global header, `opennec.h` which has a bunch of includes for `<math.h>` and so forth. It also has a couple of basic definitions:

```
#define NUM_COMNTS  5
char *comment_codes[NUM_COMNTS] =
{
  "CM", "CE", "!", "'", "#"
};
```

These caused complaints because of multiple definitions (of course) so I did what I forgot to do the first time and added guards:

```
#ifndef COMNT_CODES_DEF
#define COMNT_CODES_DEF
#define NUM_COMNTS  5
char *comment_codes[NUM_COMNTS] =
{
  "CM", "CE", "!", "'", "#"
};
#endif
```

And yet...

```
duplicate symbol _comment_codes in:
    calculations.o
    somnec.o
```

Ok, what did I do wrong?

Comment: http://c-faq.com/decl/decldef.html

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164167/variable-declaration-in-a-header-file, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files

Answer (score 4):

Your `comment_codes` symbol is going to need a **declaration** in a header file,

```
#ifndef COMNT_CODES_DEF
#define COMNT_CODES_DEF
#define NUM_COMNTS  5
extern char *comment_codes[NUM_COMNTS];
#endif
```

and a **definition** in one (and only one) c file.

```
#include "comnt_codes.h"

char *comment_codes[NUM_COMNTS] = {
  "CM", "CE", "!", "'", "#"
};
```

Otherwise every c file that includes your comment-codes header will provide conflicting definitions of `comment_codes`.

Comment: Ah HA. I thought you only needed that with function definitions, as pretty much everything I've ever read implies, but in retrospect it's obvious.

Comment: Just for the next person that comes here, for my own needs I placed the declarations in my main header and the implementation in main.c, as that was ultimately going to be the only consumer.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz If you only have one consumer, you can remove the declaration from the header and put a `static` definition in the c file, giving you a "module local" variable.

Comment: You don't need any headers until you have more than one source file for a program that will share some code. As soon as you have more than one source file, you need a header, because you won't use two source files if there isn't something shared between the two, even if it is only a simple function call. Headers declare what's shared. Source files define what the headers declare. Make everything static at file scope except `main()` and any entry point functions — or global variables. Make sure that everything that uses the functions or variables includes the header; it provides cross-checks.

Comment: Currently the code shares these values, although they are *actively* used in only one file. I'll either remove them from the header or factor out the code in question from main at some point.